# Misplaced Terminal.app

Tags: mac, terminal

How can I find Terminal.app manually?
I believe that I moved it somewhere using a command line like this:

```
sudo mv Terminal.app ./Desktop
```

It didn't show up on my desktop, and it isn't in Applications anywhere

Comment: Can't the search engine on the top of your screen help you with that? There isn't much I like with Macs, but the search engine isn't one of them. It's really well-made.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't *re*move it?

Answer (score 0):

Terminal is in /Applications/Utilities/ by default.

If you actually moved it, try typing Terminal in the Spotlight menu and pressing ⌘↩ (command-return). (If ⌘↩ doesn't do anything, it's probably because of the [Apple Events bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74107/safari-6s-show-reveal-in-finder-stopped-working/74111#74111) in 10.8.2.)

If even that doesn't work, try running this in AppleScript Editor:

```
POSIX path of (path to application "Terminal")
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the command you typed, terminal is now named 'Desktop' and is still in your /Applications/Utilities folder (since you would have had to be in that folder for the command to do anything at all).

Take a look in there for stray Desktops :)